# Julia SymPy.det(M) does not work but SymPy.det([M[1] M[2]; M[3] M[4]]) works

Tags: julia

I am using `det` from `SymPy` to compute the determinant of a symbolic matrix `M` with type `Array{Number,2}`. `SymPy.det(M)` produces the error

> TypeError("can't convert expression to float")

whereas `SymPy.det([M[1] M[2]; M[3] M[4]])` (the argument has type `Array{SymPy.Sym,2}`) computes the determinant without error.

Why is this happening? And how should I go around it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems that the difference in the types of `M` and `[M[1] M[2]; M[3] M[4]]` is causing the problem. `M` needs to be of type `Array{SymPy.Sym,2}`.

Comment: Right, `M` is not symbolic if it has type `Array{Number, 2}` -- that's a normal Julia matrix of an abstract type. If you construct it by hand, try to write something like `M = SymPy.Sym[1 2; 3 4]`.